# Find Salesforce ORG where a connected app lives using client id

Tags: sandbox, connected-apps, org

This is a bit of a weird question but I am unable to locate the sandbox a specific connected app lives under.We are looking at multiple prod orgs with many sandboxes underneath and haven't  been able to find it yet. Tried cheating the system by hitting the standard test domain hoping something would point at the real domain behind the client_id but the response does not indicate anything:

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9GiqKapCZBwFbL74c4xggK0dfEOLAfRXloVgz.aDHEWNvHZYCIx3v5H7tnFtAHJUyFT7YpmMKg6wrlPBq&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without having to open every connected app in every sandbox would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to write a script that runs through the oAuth authorization for each sandbox. Assuming a vanilla connected app config where you don't require a signature via a JWT and the users are pre-authorized via a profile or a permission set, going in with a [username/password flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=0) would be our recommendation.